# Content sources for my Search service

Tags: 2013, search

I am confused on how content sources work for search service in SharePoint 2013.  Currently I have a web application at `http://gvstg01:40708`, and my current search content sources are:-

- `http://gvstg01`
- `http://gvstg01:40708`

My question is whether  defining `http://gvstg01:40708`  as a content source is redundant ? as `http://gvstg01` will cover `http://gvstg01:40708` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the URLs provided these seem to be two different Web Applications. The one without port number is port 80 site and other is at 40708 port.
You can add more than one web application in a content source. When you add a web application to content source, all its site collections are covered automatically. However, in your case the second URL is that of Web Application. Hence it won't be covered by only adding first one. Moreover, you can choose to have one content source and add these two web applications in that.